# Getting the value of 'Pointer 1' through 'Pointer 3'

Tags: c++, pointers

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;

    int *aPtr1 = &a;
    int *aPtr2 = aPtr1;
    int *aPtr3 = aPtr2;

    cout << "'a' value: " << a << endl;
    cout << "'aPtr1' value: " << *aPtr1 << endl;
    cout << "'aPtr2' value: " << *aPtr2 << endl;
    cout << "'aPtr2' value from 'aPtr3': " << **aPtr3 << endl;
}
```

In here, at the last line, I am trying to get the 'aPtr2' value from 'aPtr3'. In other words, this is my attempt to find the 'Pointer Before'. But it gives me the error

```
PointerTest.cpp:16: error: invalid type argument of `unary *'
```

How can I make this OK? Please help!

Comment: aPtr3 isn't a pointer to a pointer... you can't dereference it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aPtr3` is equal to `aPtr2`. And `aPtr2` is the adress of `a`. When writing `*aPtr3`, you already access the value pointed by the adress it contains (ie, the adress of `a`).

If you wanted to use this syntax, you should have had

```
int **aPtr3 = &aPtr2;
```

Answer (score 2):

`**aPtr3` evokes Undefined Behavior.  `aPtr3` isn't a pointer-to-pointer-to-int; it is a pointer-to-int.  Fix the code by simply doing:

`<< *aPtr3 << endl`

Your code evoked Undefined Behavior because `**aPtr3` boils down to `*5`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I really appreciate it :) +1 from me